# Trouble verifying a solution to a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, physics, algebraic-manipulation

I am reading a physics book which has discussed one approach towards solving the differential equation

$$
\frac{d^2 x(t)}{dt^2} = Cx(t)
$$

as follows:

> [image]

**Using Mathematica to solve the equation.** I tried using Mathematica to solve the equation as follows:

```
In[4]:= DSolve[x''[t] == C x[t], x[t], t]

Out[4]= {{x[t] -> E^(Sqrt[c] t) C[1] + E^(-Sqrt[c] t) C[2]}}
```

But it gives a different (and I assume more general/proper) solution than the one offered by the book.

**Question:** How can I verify that the solution offered in the physics book has a form which matches the solution offered by Mathematica?

**Attempt:** Trying

```
Solve[E^(Sqrt[C] t) C[1] + E^(-Sqrt[C] t) C[2] == 
  C[1] Cos[Sqrt[-C] t] + C[2] Sin[Sqrt[-C] t], C]
```

yields

[image]

Comment: If you just want the solution in the textbook you can `DSolve[x''[t] == -ω^2 x[t], x[t], t]`. Prove the solution involving $C$ is equivalent to that involving $\omega$ is another story, though.

Comment: Why square `ω` in that DSolve equation? Isn't `x''[t] == -ω^2 x[t]` a different differential equation than `x''[t] == C x[t]`?

Comment: `Solve[ω == Sqrt[-c], c]` => `{{c -> -ω^2}}`

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to extend my comments to an answer. If one just want to obtain the result in textbook, we just need

```
ref = DSolve[x''[t] == -ω^2 x[t], x[t], t][[1]]
(* {x[t] -> C[1] Cos[t ω] + C[2] Sin[t ω]} *)
```

because as mentioned in the screenshot, $-\omega^2=C$.

However, if one wants to prove the output of

```
sol = DSolve[x''[t] == c x[t], x[t], t][[1]]
(* {x[t] -> E^(Sqrt[c] t) C[1] + E^(-Sqrt[c] t) C[2]} *)
```

is equivalent to `ref` given that `-ω^2 == c`, the process is a bit involved. We need to:

1. Substitute in `-ω^2 == c` and express the solution with `Sinh` and `Cosh`.

   ```
   sol /. c -> -ω^2 // ExpToTrig
   (* {x[t] -> 
      C[1] Cosh[t Sqrt[-ω^2]] + C[2] Cosh[t Sqrt[-ω^2]] + 
      C[1] Sinh[t Sqrt[-ω^2]] - C[2] Sinh[t Sqrt[-ω^2]]} *)
   ```
2. Expand the `Sqrt[-ω^2]` with `PowerExpand`. Notice `Assumptions -> True` is necessary to obtain a generally correct result.

   ```
   PowerExpand[%, Assumptions -> True] // Simplify
   (* {x[t] -> (C[1] + C[2]) Cos[(-1)^Ceiling[Arg[ω]/π] t ω] + 
             I (C[1] - C[2]) Sin[(-1)^Ceiling[Arg[ω]/π] t ω]} *)
   ```
3. At this point it's obvious that `(-1)^Ceiling[Arg[ω]/π]` can only be $\pm 1$, but still, we stick on proving with *Mathematica*. We simplify `(-1)^…` term with `FullSimplify`.

   ```
   % /. (-1)^a_ :> FullSimplify[(-1)^a]
   (* {x[t] -> (C[1] + C[2])*Cos[t*ω*Piecewise[{{-1, Arg[ω] > 0}}, 1]] + 
             I*(C[1] - C[2])*Sin[t*ω*Piecewise[{{-1, Arg[ω] > 0}}, 1]]} *)
   ```
4. Finally simplify the `Piecewise[…]` further by classified discussion.

   ```
   Simplify[%, #] & /@ {Arg[ω] > 0, Arg[ω] <= 0}
   (* {{x[t] -> (C[1] + C[2]) Cos[t ω] - I (C[1] - C[2]) Sin[t ω]}, 
       {x[t] -> (C[1] + C[2]) Cos[t ω] + I (C[1] - C[2]) Sin[t ω]}} *)
   ```

`C[1]` and `C[2]` are constants, thus `C[1] + C[2]` and `± I (C[1] - C[2])` are constants, too. QED.

Answer (score 1):

Since Mathematica uses a symbol similar to C for arbitrary constants in the solutions provided by `DSolve`, I suggest using a different symbol like MU to avoid confusion. If MU is positive in your original equation, you will get one type of solution, if negative another. To see this, try `DSolve[x''[t]==3 x[t], x[t], t]` and  `DSolve[x''[t]==-3 x[t], x[t], t]`. With that, you should be able to understand the general solution you are getting.

Or try getting rid of the arbitrary constants by supplying initial conditions as

`sol = DSolve[{x''[t] == MU x[t], x[0] == AA, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t]`

And then

`sol /. MU -> 3 // ExpToTrig  // Simplify`

And

`sol /. MU -> -3  // ExpToTrig // Simplify`

to see what is going on.

Recall Cosh[x] will increase with x (look up the definition), which makes sense from the original equation.

(Normally it is best practice to not use upper-case names like MU or AA.)